# Income chart fetching only 2 months data using carbon

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have this code to display an income chart bar showing last 11 months bars from the current but fetching and displaying data from the last 2 months only

Here is the code:

```
<---------


public function incomeChartData(): array
    {
        $manualPayment = Subscription::wherePaymentType('paid')
            ->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->year)->get()
            ->groupBy(function ($q) {
                return Carbon::parse($q->created_at)->isoFormat('MMM');
            });

        $transactions = Transaction::whereStatus(1)
            ->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->year)->get()
            ->groupBy(function ($q) {
                return Carbon::parse($q->created_at)->isoFormat('MMM');
            });

        $data = [];
        $periods = now()->startOfMonth()->subMonths(11)->monthsUntil(now());
        $labels = [];
        $dataset = [];
        $colors = [];
        $borderColors = [];
        foreach ($periods as $key => $period) {
            $month = $period->isoFormat('MMM');
            $labels[] = $month;
            $colors[] = getBGColors($key).')';
            $borderColors[] = getBGColors($key).', 0.75)';
            $amounts = isset($transactions[$month])
                ? $transactions[$month]->pluck('amount')->toArray() : [0];
            $amounts = isset($manualPayment[$month])
                ? array_merge($amounts, $manualPayment[$month]->pluck('payable_amount')->toArray()) : $amounts;
            $dataset[] = removeCommaFromNumbers(number_format(array_sum($amounts), 2));
        }

        $data['labels'] = $labels;
        $data['breakDown'][] = [
            'label' => __('messages.common.total_amount'),
            'data' => $dataset,
            'backgroundColor' => $colors,
            'borderColor' => $borderColors,
            'lineTension' => 0.5,
            'radius' => 4,
        ];

        return $data;
    }
}


--------->
```

Please help where I am wrong and how to display data from every month?

I tried to change the months using carbon but since I am a newbie, I cannot find a solution.

I am expecting the income chart to show data from every month.

Comment: Did you try and dump `toSql()` on your queries to inspect that your query looks what you're expecting?

Comment: No, I am a newbie and thus don't know how to fix it

Comment: You have a condition to get only the data of current year `->whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->year)` so obviously it will only show the last 2 months. If we were on December, it would show all months.

Comment: I was also thinking the same. So, what should I use there to show all months?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar project where I need to make chart bars. Soo, this query helped me. First I get dates and price and then group data by months and pass them in blade file.

```
             $charges = DB::table('city_drivers')
            ->join('cities', 'city_drivers.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
            ->where('city_drivers.user_id', $id) 
            ->select('city_drivers.date', 'cities.price')
            ->get();

        // Group the results by month
        $chargesData = $charges->groupBy(function ($item) {
            return Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('M');
        });

        $chargeMonths = [];
        $chargePrice = [];

        foreach ($chargesData as $chargeMonth => $values) {
            // Calculate the total price for the month
            $totalPrice = $values->sum('price');

            $chargeMonths[] = $chargeMonth;
            $chargePrice[] = $totalPrice;
        }
```

In blade file

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _ycharge = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($chargeMonths) !!}');
    var _xcharge = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($chargePrice) !!}');
</script>
```

In JS I used bar chart

```
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';


var allMonths = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

// Create an array for prices, matching the order of allMonths
var prices = allMonths.map(function(month) {
  // Check if the current month is in _yticket
  var index = _ycharge.indexOf(month);
  if (index !== -1) {
    // If the month is in _yticket, use the corresponding price from _xticket
    return _xcharge[index];
  } else {
    // If the month is not in _yticket, use null as a placeholder
    return null;
  }
});

// Bar Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCityChart");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: allMonths, // Show all months on the X-axis
    datasets: [{
      label: "Price",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      data: prices, // Use the prices array with placeholders for missing months
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'category',
        time: {
          unit: 'month'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 12, // Show all months
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          maxTicksLimit: 9,
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

I hope it helps. :)